# How to populate two array deleting duplicate numbers

Tags: c, arrays

I need to populate a first array with 20 numbers then I have to populate a second array using the numbers of the first array but without duplicate.

My question is: which is the best way to do this?

The only way I've found is:

1. populate the first array
2. populate the second array using the same numbers
3. delete duplicates from the second array

but I suppose this is not the best solution. Any suggestion?

Comment: While populating the second array, check if the number you want to put in the second array is already there, and if yes, just skip it. Come up with an attempt and then we can help.

Comment: Why the second step? Is the order matter?

Comment: If you want to be fancy, you can copy, sort and then remove consecutively equal elements. But it won't run any better than a nested loop

Comment: @StoryTeller For 20 numbers it wont.. for 2M numbers it will run significantly faster (well, depending on the sorting algorithm, of course..).

Comment: @EugeneSh. removing non-unique elements in place (which means you have to shrink the array, by copying forward) will still be quardic in complexity.

Comment: If you don't mind sorting the original array, you can do the copy in a single iteration, just skip anything that is equal to the previous thing you copied. *That* will be faster than a nested loop.

Comment: @StoryTeller I think you can "shrink" a sorted array linearly even in place... Something like running two indices one from the first to last, and the second from last to first, skipping the equal elements and swapping.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You'd have to demonstrate. Because I have a strong suspicion it will mess up the sorted order.

Comment: @StoryTeller It will definitely! But we don't have a requirement to keep it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Messing up the order at the end of the range before you reach it, will make it difficult to check if two consecutive elements are equal :) But it may be possible to have our cake and eat it too, since `std::unique` in c++ promises that.

Comment: @StoryTeller it won\`t. At least if implemented like this: http://ideone.com/qEfiOo

Answer (score -1):

homework?

One approach would be to sort the array (search for `qsort`). Then duplicate elimination is as simple as copying the numbers from array 1 to array 2 skipping all equal numbers.